# Alternative to sleep for sending data to a socket right after it's opened

Tags: c++, matlab, sockets, boost, boost-asio

Consider this piece of code opening a socket using bost and sending some data:

```
boost::asio::io_service service;
tcp::resolver resolver(service);
tcp::resolver::query query(tcp::v4(), "localhost", 2000);
tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve( query );
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(service);
socket.connect(*iterator);
boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(data, size));
```

If the receiver is coded in C++ with boost it can receive the data. However, we are trying to receive the data from Matlab, and this one does not receive the data:

```
t=tcpip('localhost', 2000, 'NetworkRole', 'server');
fopen(t);
// Now we launch the C++ code above from another process
// Now t.BytesAvailable remains 0
```

To have the data be received, we need to insert a sleep between `socket.connect` and `boost::asio::write`, then it works well (as this post mentioned it https://stackoverflow.com/a/20274486/3336423....).

I really hate having to do that (add sleep in my code). Is there any alternative? Is there a sort of `is_ready` attribute or something similar I could use to know when I can send the data and be sure the listener will get it?

Extra bonus question: Is it a kind of Matlab bug? As sleep is not needed when receiver is a C++/boost application....does only Matlab need this sleep to be operated in order to receive the first set of data transmitted?

Comment: Can you change the protocol and have Matlab send a packet whenever it's ready?

Comment: No, we have no communication between Matlab and the C++ program, and we'de like to keep it simple, so we don't want to add one.

Comment: why not use a deadline_timer instead of sleep. But again, that would not work deterministically.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the analysis on that linked answer, and it very much appears that Matlab is being buggy.

There's not going to be a solution to that unless you can fix the server (*or* if Matlab documents a protocol to reliable start the communications)

**Note**: you can use Asio to do asynchronous IO operations. It also comes with a deadline timer. So, if your gripe is that `sleep` blocks operations, that can be circumvented with slightly more complicated asynchronous calls.